# Avoid repeating for Like button, similar to facebook LIKE

Tags: jquery, postgresql

I have a **like button on my site which is similar to facebook's LIKE**, where it **doesn't accept duplication** as user needs to mandatorily login to like the button

Here the **problem is when user continuously clicks the button its taking the duplicates**, sometimes even its going for negatives as well

Throught **jquery Async false** we can avoid the new request unless old request is closed, but read somewhere that its not recommended by W3C, so can anyone help me to overcome this issue as what could be the best practise for this scenario and also what kinda practice does Facebook following if known to anyone.

Comment: after click disable the like for some seconds or permanently

Answer (score 0):

I would block the request on the server side, never trust input from the user side.

When you store the like in your database with the user ID and item they liked, simply check if the like is already present in your database before doing a write.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the last request is closed or not by setting a flag.

```
var isInAjax = false;
$("#button").click(function(){        
    if(!isInAjax )
    {
        isInAjax = true;
        $.ajax({ 
            //code here
            }).done(function(){
                    isInAjax = false;
            }).fail(function(){
                    isInAjax = false;
            });
    }
});
```